# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types error shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

My code is this

```
    private MyCatch _catch = new MyCatch("Description");

    decimal getTotalValue(GridView view, int listSourceRowIndex)
    {
        decimal unitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "Each"));  //Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types
        decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "Quantity"));
        decimal discount = Convert.ToDecimal(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "TaxPercentage"));
        return unitPrice * quantity * (1 - discount);
    }

    private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "Totalototal" && e.IsGetData) e.Value =
          getTotalValue(view, e.ListSourceRowIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I assume, in case of Null it set the unitPrice to 0.

```
decimal unitPrice = view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "Each") == DBNull.Value
                                ? 0
                                : Convert.ToDecimal(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "Each"));
```

Comment: Hi Nair, Thankz a lot

Answer (score 2):

If there can be null value try using nullable types.

```
decimal? unitPrice = ...
```

A nullable type is a value type that accepts null as a value. You can then check value

```
if (unitPrice.HasValue) // is there a value or null?
    unitPrice.Value // do something with the value
```

More about nullables on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

But I assume that null should not be received, it would make the calculation impossible. Therefore I would advise to encapsulate fetching values in a `try/catch` block instead and return from method if some of the calls throws an exception.

Comment: Hi Ondrej, nullable means how ? Am new to c# help me.

Comment: @SriHari I will explain.

Comment: @SriHari ..Please see my answer below

Comment: Hi Ondrej, Thanks I got an Idea about DBNull

Answer (score 1):

you can use `TryParse` method to identify whether cast is possible from given value to decimal or not.if not possible assign the `DBNull.Value`

**Syntax:** `decimal.TryParse(value,out parameter)`

the above function return `true` if the value can be castable to `decimal`
return `false` when casting is not possible

when you need to insert `Null` into table column you should insert `DBNull.Value` from the code.
 so you can send `DBNull.Value` when the casting is not possible.

*Note:* here i have used ternary `?:` operator to write the whole thing in single line
**Solution:**

```
 decimal result;
 decimal unitPrice =(decimal.TryParse(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "Each"),out result))?result:DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Hi Sudhakar, I tried but again error in that above line as "Best overloaded Method" Invalid Arguments

Comment: @SriHari : you should declare variable result, check my edited answer now

Comment: Your code results in an error.  Did you mean to have `?result:0;` instead of `?result:DBNull.Value;`?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is beacuse , the data values that are being fetched from may contain DBNull values which means that value does not exists.

So, it makes not sense in changing the type of the value that has not existed.

The solution to allow null is , declare the variable as nullable types that means they are capable of accepting null values.

The synatax is:

```
datatype? variablename
```

Hopw this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I am programming ASP.net VB using GridView with RowDataBound event, in some rows I have nulls from database:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
   If (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MyField") IsNot DBNull.Value) Then                    
       myTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MyField"))
   End If    
End If
```